# The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am working on a runner game and it is almost done. The problem is that I am testing the Pause Panel and when player touches a zombie, pause panel shows up and I am restarting the game again by pressing the restart button. But when I touch the zombie again panel doesnt show up and gives me the error in the title. I am stuck and any help will be appreciated. This is the code and I referenced to the line that error sends me :

```
[SerializeField]
private GameObject pausePanel;

[SerializeField]
private Button RestartGameButton;

[SerializeField]
private Text ScoreText;

private int score;

void Start ()
{
    pausePanel.SetActive(false);
    ScoreText.text = score + "M";
    StartCoroutine(CountScore());
}

IEnumerator CountScore()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.6f);
    score++;
    ScoreText.text = score + "M";
    StartCoroutine(CountScore());
}

void OnEnable()
{
    PlayerDeath.endgame += PlayerDiedEndTheGame;
}

void OnDisable()
{
    PlayerDeath.endgame += PlayerDiedEndTheGame;
}

void PlayerDiedEndTheGame()
{
    if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Score"))
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", 0);
    }
    else
    {
        int highscore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score");

        if(highscore < score)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", score);
        }
    }

    pausePanel.SetActive(true); //this is the line that error sends me but I cant figure it out because I didnt try to destroy the panel in the first place.
    RestartGameButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
    RestartGameButton.onClick.AddListener(() => RestartGame());
    Time.timeScale = 0f;
}

public void PauseButton()
{
    Time.timeScale = 0f;
    pausePanel.SetActive(true);
    RestartGameButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
    RestartGameButton.onClick.AddListener(() => ResumeGame());
}

public void GoToMenu()
{
    Time.timeScale = 1f;
    SceneManager.LoadScene("MainMenu");
}

public void ResumeGame()
{
    Time.timeScale = 1f;
    pausePanel.SetActive(false);
}

public void RestartGame()
{
    Time.timeScale = 1f;
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Gameplay");
}
```

Comment: What is this line: `PlayerDeath.endgame += PlayerDiedEndTheGame;` ? The second argument is a function, which is confusing considering I assume PlayerDeath.endgame is some kind of numerical type. Do you mean to add a `()` prior to the semicolon?

Comment: That function doesn't return anything either... Not sure what you are trying to do there

Comment: endgame is an event. I declared a delegate void which is named EndGame and added an event on it with the same name endgame. That class basically specifies the death conditions. If the player passes away from the screen or touches a zombie, they will die and event will appear.

Comment: You are reloading a whole new Scene.  I don't know how you're setting up your `pausePanel` GameObject but it is getting destroyed on load.  You need, SHOULD, be using DontDestroyOnLoad for this menu.  Also, I think you want to remove (`-`) `PlayerDiedEndTheGame` in the `OnDisable` method.

Comment: Yep that is the error. I realized it when I double-checked the methods and I forgot the change the + sign on the OnDisable method. It worked when I put - instead. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was a simple mistake on the OnDisable method. I deleted the += sign and changed it with -= sign because it was enabling the event when it was supposed to disable.